# Processing multiple columns in the dataset into one column for modeling

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, statistics, data-preprocessing

I want to predict spatio-temporal data and I found STNN (Spatio Temporal Neural Network) research with the github repository here (https://github.com/edouardelasalles/stnn), at the end of the repo description, it is explained regarding the dataset but I have difficulty understanding how a data spatial with its attributes transformed into only 1 dimension and then crossed with the time dimension into only 2 dimensions?

my question is how to convert dataset with multiple columns for example:

| x | y | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 9 | 8 | 7 |
| 122 | 3 | 8 | 7 | 9 |
| 312 | 2 | 8 | 9 | 7 |

to:

| formulated |
| --- |
| 0,123 |
| 0,412 |
| 0,213 |

is there any way and formula to do that? Thankyou!

Comment: I thought the spatial data is just 2d adjacency matrix of size `[41, 41]`. and the original data is `[200, 41, 1]`. The main parameter is `factors` with size of `[200, 41, 1]` (The last channel is latent size dimension)

Comment: To train decoder, at each timestep, for each spatial node, we extract `factors[t_idx, x_idx]` with size `[1]`, and passthrough `decoder` (linear layer) to get `x_recon`

Comment: To train dynamic, we extract `factors[t_idx]` (size `[41, 1]`) and multiply with its `x_idx` adjacency row (size `[41]`) to size `[41, 41]`. It is then flatten and pass through `dynamic` (MLP) to next timestep latent state, and optimize its mse